# Gmail email send c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, send

This code works when i try send message to this same email but on other, don't works without error

```
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("notreply.authservice@gmail.com", "myapppass"),
            EnableSsl = true,
        };

        smtpClient.Send("notreply.authservice@gmail.com", "email", "Authorization!", "body");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Does gmail/google still supports SMTP? ... Try do some research on this topic

Comment: @Selvin SMTP is the only protocol used for delivering emails, so yes Gmail supports it. The real question is what type of credentials are used?

Comment: Provide at least the error that you get, envolve the code inside a try/catch to provide us with the error

Comment: Whats the erorr?

Comment: Try using port 465. Also you need to set up 2-step verification and create an app password

Comment: I have app password, i set port to 463 and i get this error SocketException: The connection attempt failed because the connected side did not respond correctly after a set period of time, or the connection created failed because the connected host did not respond 64.233.162.109:463

Comment: When i have 587 port i don't have any error but message doesn't get sended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting the message as I have here. and use Authenticate instead of NetworkCredential.

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    From = "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    To = "xxx1@gmail.com",
    MessageText = "test",
    Subject = "test"
};

try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        client.Authenticate(message.From, "AppsPassword");
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    public MimeMessage GetMessage()
    {
        var body = MessageText;
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("test", From));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("test", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this works but you can say how to add html text?

Comment: Nope i haven tried that yet.   Might be a good idea for my next tutorial thanks

Comment: what tutorials?